# Set global props value in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm importing a component library into my Vue 3 project.

Each instance of the component uses the exact same styles. To avoid manually changing the props of each instance I'm using a global property:

```
app.config.globalProperties.$tooltipStyles = { width: '300px', minWidth: 'unset' };
```

To do this, I have to import `app` into each file and `return` it in `setup()`. I also have to set it to each instance:

```
:styles="app.$tooltipStyles"
```

Is there a way to set this globally so that every time I use the component, it has these styles by default?

---

**EDIT**

To add on to the accepted answer, I created a separate file which exports a single reactive object:

```
import { reactive } from 'vue';

const global = reactive({
    $tooltipStyles: { width: '300px', minWidth: 'unset' },
    $tooltipPosition: 'right',
});

export default global;
```

This way I can update any property on the fly.

For example, when the screen is below a certain size I can change the position to `'top'`:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 992px)').matches) {
        global.$tooltipPosition = 'top';
    } else {
        global.$tooltipPosition = 'right';
    }
})
```

And it updates accordingly.

Comment: I think I would still prefer to use a more imperative way of defining these by using a file to hold the ref/reactive, and do the imports as/where needed.

Comment: How do you mean? Do you mean instead of a single reactive object, individual reactive properties?

Comment: pretty much the same way (using `reactive`) but instead of using `app.config.globalProperties` I would go with the tediousness of registering it to each component it through `import`. While there's nothing wrong with using the global object, I find that it has some drawbacks, namely that it is more likely to promote splitting up the logic and functionality. If you put the variables and the functions in one place (file) and don't tie them to the app's internals, you could have a more portable and maintainable solution (though more verbose). But TBC, it is just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got almost everything in place.

The only thing is that you don't need to specify the `app`, so you don't need to import it.

this: `:styles="$tooltipStyles"` should get your value

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({})

app.component('my-component', {
  template: '<h1 :style="$tooltipStyles">My Component {{$tooltipStyles}}</h1>',
})

app.config.globalProperties.$tooltipStyles= 'color: green;'
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the `prototypes`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$tooltipStyles = {
   width: '300px',
   minWidth: 'unset'
}
```

For more information: [Adding Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html)

With Vue mounted:

`otherFile.js`

```js
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$tooltipStyles)
}
```

Comment: This is for Vue 2 but I'm using Vue 3